# How can I graph a merge commit's history along both parents?

Tags: git

I have a merge commit. I want to graph its history along both parents. What combination of arguments to git-log will select the following commits?

- the merge commit itself
- its ancestry along all parents
- up to and including the merge-base of those parents
- but nothing earlier than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally I figured a way out shortly after posting it....

```
git log --oneline --graph --boundary somecommit somecommit^1...somecommit^2
```

I'll hold off on marking my own answer for a while in case someone has a better method, though.

Comment: Don't bother with anything beyond the format options and the start point. `git log --graph --decorate --oneline $thatcommit`.  `git log` by default traces all parents, you have to restrict its walk with `--first-parent` or `--ancestry-path` or `--no-walk`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your specific commit is a merge commit, we want:

1. To get its parents:

   ```
   git rev-parse $commit^@
   ```

   This syntax means "all the parents of the commit, but not the commit itself".  (If you know it's a two-commit merge, `$commit^1 $commit^2` will name both parents.  the `$...^@` trick finds all its parents, whatever they are.  The count of the number of commits returned from this `rev-parse` tells you whether this is a root commit—zero parents—or an ordinary commit with 1 parent, or a merge.)
2. To find all the merge bases of its parents:

   ```
   git merge-base --all $(git rev-parse $commit^@)
   ```

   Ideally we should be able to do `git merge-base --all $commit^@`, but this doesn't work (a minor bug in `git merge-base`: it does not accept all the normal rev-parse syntax).
3. Now that we have the merge bases, we want to exclude their parents, but not they themselves.  Once again, the odd `$hash^@` syntax is the way to go, in case they themselves are merges with multiple parents, or even the root commit with no parents:

   ```
   find_stopargs() {
       set -- $(git merge-base --all $(git rev-parse $1^@))
       # if $# is 0, then either $1 was not a merge, or its
       # parents have unrelated histories
       for i do echo "^$i^@"; done
   }
   ```

Now we can select `$commit` as a starting point for a graph walk, and use `$(find_stopargs $commit)` as the stopping points for this walk.  Add options to suit (e.g., `--decorate --oneline --graph`).  Add `--ancestry-path` to avoid walks that follow additional side tracks:

```
...--o--X--*--o--o   <-- br1
      \     \     \
       U1-U2-o--o--o    <-- br2
```

If your starting point is the tip commit of `br2`, its two parents are `br1` and `br2^`.  Their merge base is commit `*`, so we will exclude its parent `X`, but the graph walk will show the two unwanted `U` commits.

[ElpieKay's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522572/1256452) will work fine for many ordinary cases of a two-parent merge with a single merge base.  Add `--ancestry-path` to avoid including the unwanted `U` commits.

[Your own variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522571/1256452) using `--boundary` and the symmetric difference logically *ought* to work, but in practice, Git's `--boundary` code winds up including way too many boundary commits if the graph is a bit tangled.  If you don't mind mentally excluding them, this is the simplest way.

Comment: Etiquette question: My answer is the simplest here and does exactly what I asked, but yours is much more thorough, if harder to follow. I've upvoted you, but which should I mark as the answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that one. If you like, I could move the link to your answer to the top, and add that it usually does work. (Git has to follow multiple walk-paths to get multiple commits marked as boundary commits and then, because of `--boundary`, show all of them, for it to misfire. Try it on the Git repository for Git, which is where I first observed the problem, and eventually gave up on `--boundary` in scripts.)

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git merge-base HEAD^ HEAD^2)^..HEAD
```

- `HEAD^` is the first parent and `HEAD^2` is the second parent.
- `git merge-base HEAD^ HEAD^2` returns their merge-base.
- `$(merge-base)^` is the first parent of the merge-base.